# Migrate custom field in Activity object

Tags: custom-field, data-loader, migration-tool, migration, activities

I've added a custom field to the Activities object which I'm trying to migrate data into using the Data Loader on the Event sub-object. However, when I'm creating the map for loading, I do not see my custom field as an option. I've tried restarting the Data Loader but that doesn't help. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: did you set the custom field to be accessible for the logged in user in data loader?

Comment: The user for Data Loader is the root admin, and should have access to the field. I'm not sure where I can view the access permissions for the field, but if you're referring to field-level security, then no, the read-only checkbox is unchecked for the sysadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the field level security of the particular field. make it visible for your profile and then try accessing it via API.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. What I don't understand is why I didn't have to set the field-level accessibility to Visible for my profile for other custom fields in other objects such as Accounts, Contacts, etc. I was able to migrate the data over using this profile even though the field was not visible to it.

Comment: My guess is that You must not have forgotten to make the custom fields visible for your particular profile when you were creating them.